# Jtree subfolders not being displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using a Jtree to display some folders. It was working but now I find that subfolders are not being displayed. This is my first time using swing and I am not sure what I did wrong. I have pasted my code for the tree below, I have followed examples and used get last path but am not sure where I went wrong and why the subfolders do not display. My subfolders are separated by an underscore (_) This code is basically called by another class for the UI. This is the tree code :

```
  public DRUDRDesc getUDRType() {
        JTree tree = browser.getUDRTypeTree();
        TreePath descTreePath = tree.getSelectionPath();
        if (descTreePath != null) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) descTreePath
                    .getLastPathComponent();
            if (selectedNode.isLeaf()) {
                return (DRUDRDesc) selectedNode.getUserObject();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Your posted **tree code** shows only a method to get the selected-nodes User-Object. This code should not be the reason why your subfolders are not beeing displayed.